# Can you really wait on Condition Variable with WaitFor...Object(s)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization

I'm trying to implement some sort of waiting on many `CONDITION_VARIABLE`. 
[The answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410649/waiting-for-multiple-condition-variables-in-boost) imply that `WaitForMultipleObjects` and such are valid options when dealing with Windows API (and many more places over the internet), but it appears that it is not the case.

first of all, nowhere in the MSDN documentation it is written that a Windows Condition variable is a valid argument for `WaitFor...` functions. 
Second of all, it appears that `WaitFor...` only accepts `HANDLE` type as argument, which is basically a kernel object. but `PCONDITION_VARIABLE` is not really a `HANDLE`.
finally, trying to use a condition variable (both as a `PCONDITION_VARIABLE` and the undocumented `CONDITION_VARIABLE::Ptr`) makes the functions return error code 6 (invalid handle)

for example:

```
    CONDITION_VARIABLE cv;
    InitializeConditionVariable(&cv);
    auto res = WaitForSingleObject(cv.Ptr, INFINITE); //returns immediately
    if (res != WAIT_OBJECT_0) { 
        auto ec = GetLastError();
        std::cout << ec << "\n";
    }
```

so, can you really wait on a condition variable or it's just an urban legend?

Comment: Condition variables are user mode objects.  WaitFor... can only wait on kernel handles.

Comment: I don't see anything in the linked answer that implies, what you make of it. First of all, it is talking about `boost::condition_variable`, not [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or [CONDITION_VARIABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052.aspx). And none of the answers imply, that the `WaitForXxx` family of functions can be used with those (the accepted answer explicitly states *"if you're willing to restrict your code to Windows synchronization primitives"*). Sorry, -1 for being poorly researched.

Comment: what about "Of course, Windows has WaitForMultipleObjects as aJ posted, which could be a solution if you're willing to restrict your code to Windows synchronization primitives." in a question about condition variable, I see this as an imply that condition variable works with waitfor...

Comment: What about *"if you're willing to restrict your code to **Windows synchronization primitives**"*? `std::condition_variable` is not a Windows synchronization primitive.

Comment: I AM ASKING ABOUT WINDOWS PRIMITIVE!

Comment: You don't know what you are asking about. A happy mixture of `std::condition_variable`, `boost::condition_variable`, `CONDITION_VARIABLE` and Windows synchronization primitives. As I said, I downvoted this question for being poorly researched.

Comment: where exactly are the words `std::condition_variable` or `boost::condition_variable` written in my question?

Comment: They are incorporated by way of linking to a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410649/waiting-for-multiple-condition-variables-in-boost) that is about `std::condition_variable` and `boost::condition_variable`. If that is news to you, all the more reason to downvote this question for sloppy research.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You wait for *one* with `SleepConditionVariableCS`. I'm not sure it makes sense to wait for multiple condition variables, as that implies that you're holding several critical sections and want to release all of them at once. (This might make sense, but I believe it's so rare that you're kind of expected to implement your own.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I am  trying to implement a psuedo `when_any` or `when_all`

Comment: @DavidHaim I believe your best bet is the method in the accepted answer of the question you linked. (That is, use one condition variable and check the state of the world when it's signalled.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so and it doesn't make any sense.

First of all, the `WaitForXxx` functions operate (mostly) on dispatcher objects - a subset of kernel objects including timers, events, mutexes, sempahores, threads and process (and a few internal object types like `KAGTE`s and `KQUEUE`s, but not access tokens or file mapping objects) that have a `DISPATCHER_HEADER`. It certainly won't work on user mode constructs that the kernel is unaware of.

Second, note that when you sleep ("wait") on a condition variable you have to specify whether this is critical section-based condition variable or a SRWL-based condition variable by using the correct function - either `SleepConditionVariableCS` or `SleepConditionVariableSRW`. So again, Windows (not only the kernel) has no idea what kind of condition variable you're passing it, but it needs this information to operate correctly. Since you don't provide this information to `WaitForXxx` it follows that they cannot be used with condition variables.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer to your question is **no**. You cannot use the `WaitForXxx` functions with the [condition variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052.aspx) provided by the Windows synchronization APIs. From the linked documentation:

> Condition variables are synchronization primitives that enable threads to wait until a particular condition occurs. Condition variables are user-mode objects that cannot be shared across processes.

The `WaitForXxx` functions accept parameters of the generic `HANDLE` type, which represents a handle to a kernel object. Condition variables are *user-mode* objects, not *kernel* objects, so you cannot use them with these functions, since they work only with kernel objects.

Moreover, the documentation for these functions is pretty explicit about which types of objects they can wait on, and condition variables are not on that list. For instance, [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) says:

> The `WaitForMultipleObjects` function can specify handles of any of the following object types in the *lpHandles* array:
>
> - Change notification
> - Console input
> - Event
> - Memory resource notification
> - Mutex
> - Process
> - Semaphore
> - Thread
> - Waitable timer

They all have the same list, so no confusion there.

Technically speaking (and we're diving into undocumented implementation details here, so you shouldn't rely on this as gospel), the Win32 `WaitForSingleObject` and `WaitForMultipleObjects` functions are built upon the `KeWaitForSingleObject` and `KeWaitForMultipleObjects` functions provided by the kernel subsystem. You can divide the objects supported by the kernel into three basic categories: dispatcher objects, I/O objects/data structures, and everything else. The first category, dispatcher objects, are the lowest level objects and they are all represented using the same `DISPATCHER_HEADER` data structure in their bodies. Dispatcher objects are the only types of objects that are "waitable". It is this `DISPATCHER_HEADER` structure that makes an object waitable, by definition. If the object is represented using this data structure, then it can be passed to the kernel synchronization functions. Thus, the same rules would apply to the Win32 functions.

This entire question seems to be based around a single statement that Managu makes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410718/366904): *"Windows has WaitForMultipleObjects as aJ posted, which could be a solution if you're willing to restrict your code to Windows synchronization primitives."* Perhaps he doesn't consider condition variables (as they are implemented by Windows) to be synchronization primitives, or perhaps he is just wrong. aJ's answer, to which he refers, is pretty clear about stating that `WaitForMultipleObjects` is used "to wait for multiple kernel objects," and we have already established that condition variables are not kernel objects. Either way, I don't see any evidence for an "urban legend" that you can do this.

Obviously you cannot use the `WaitForXxx` family of functions with `boost::condition_variable`, or `std::condition_variable`, or anything else.  I'm sure you already knew that, but your question has confused some people because it links to a question that refers to the Boost implementation.

It is not especially clear to me why you would need to wait on multiple condition variables simultaneously. I guess you could write your own implementation of condition variables, based on the classic Win32 synchronization primitives, such as mutexes, which you can then wait on with `WaitForMultipleObjects`. You can probably find examples of such code online, since condition variables did not become part of the operating system until Vista. For example, [this article](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html) discusses strategies for implementing condition variables in Windows as they are defined by the POSIX Pthreads specification. You could also look into using [Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655.aspx).

Comment: The list doesn't include file handles though you can wait on those, so there is some confusion. Now that we've established that this list isn't exhaustive, the absence of *whatever* from the list can't be used as evidence.

Comment: @conio Well, there is a reason the list doesn't include file handles. They are only waitable under very specific, limited situations that involve overlapped I/O. And with overlapped I/O, an event is already tied to the operation, so you really aren't waiting on the file handle—you're waiting on that event. See also: [WaitForSingleObject on a file handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775014/waitforsingleobject-on-a-file-handle)

Comment: I didn't say there weren't a reason. I said the list isn't exhaustive. This is fact, and that's all. I didn't say that waiting on file handles is extremely useful or anything of this kind. Therefore the rest of your comment is irrelevant on top of it being incorrect. You *don't* have to set the `hEvent`field of an `OVERLAPPED` struct and it's unnecessary if you have only one asynchronous action at a time or you don't care about it's completion  (see MSDN and the example in Richter's book). Again: that's not incredibly useful, but there isn't **necessarily** an event tied to the operation.

Comment: If you call `WaitForSingleObject` passing it a file a handle you are waiting on the file handle. It's senseless to argue otherwise. It is true that you don't wait on a `DISPATCHER_HEADER` located at the start of the `FILE_OBJECT` but rather near the end of the struct, but so what? I didn't say otherwise. See IInspectable's comment to the accepted answer to the question you linked to and the first quote in the second answer.